# How to implement a natural sort algorithm in c++?

Tags: c++, sorting, natural-sort

I'm sorting strings that are comprised of text and numbers. 
I want the sort to sort the number parts as numbers, not alphanumeric.

For example I want: abc1def, ..., abc9def, abc10def

instead of: abc10def, abc1def, ..., abc9def

Does anyone know an algorithm for this (in particular in c++)

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number

Comment: Look in the "related" sidebar....

Comment: @dmckee - to be fair he didn't use the term (as I didn't when I asked the same question) "Natural Sorting" - that was edited in later.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I asked [this exact question (although in Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number) and got pointed to <strike>http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html</strike> which has an algorithm and implementations of it in many languages.

Update 14 years later: Dave Koelle’s blog has gone off line and I can’t find his actual algorithm, but here’s an implementation.
https://github.com/cblanc/koelle-sort

Update 14 years and 5 months after the original answer: In the comments, it was pointed out that Dave Koelle’s blog is on the wayback machine at https://web.archive.org/web/20210207124255/davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

Comment: +1 Thanks Paul - I looked for natural sort and the C++ tag, but didn't find anything.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: It is available through the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20210207124255/davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

Answer (score 8):

Several natural sort implementations for C++ are available. A brief review:

- [`natural_sort<>`](http://web.archive.org/web/20071217040157/http://www.boostcookbook.com/Recipe:/1235053) - based on Boost.Regex.

  - In my tests, it's roughly 20 times slower than other options.
- Dirk Jagdmann's [`alnum.hpp`](http://www.davekoelle.com/files/alphanum.hpp), based on Dave Koelle's [alphanum algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)

  - Potential integer overlow issues for values over MAXINT
- Martin Pool's [`natsort`](http://sourcefrog.net/projects/natsort/) - written in C, but trivially usable from C++.

  - The only C/C++ implementation I've seen to offer a case insensitive version, which would seem to be a high priority for a "natural" sort.
  - Like the other implementations, it doesn't actually parse decimal points, but it does special case leading zeroes (anything with a leading 0 is assumed to be a fraction), which is a little weird but potentially useful.
  - PHP uses this algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

This is known as natural sorting. There's an algorithm [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20071217040157/http://www.boostcookbook.com/Recipe:/1235053) that looks promising.

Be careful of problems with non-ASCII characters (see [Jeff's blog entry](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/) on the subject).

Comment: Thats sweet but I don't have acces to boost :-|

Comment: Then it looks like Paul Tomblin's answer may be more helpful to you - the C++ variant doesn't seem to use anything funky.

Answer (score 2):

Partially reposting [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33495791/3744681):

```
bool compareNat(const std::string& a, const std::string& b){
    if (a.empty())
        return true;
    if (b.empty())
        return false;
    if (std::isdigit(a[0]) && !std::isdigit(b[0]))
        return true;
    if (!std::isdigit(a[0]) && std::isdigit(b[0]))
        return false;
    if (!std::isdigit(a[0]) && !std::isdigit(b[0]))
    {
        if (a[0] == b[0])
            return compareNat(a.substr(1), b.substr(1));
        return (toUpper(a) < toUpper(b));
        //toUpper() is a function to convert a std::string to uppercase.
    }

    // Both strings begin with digit --> parse both numbers
    std::istringstream issa(a);
    std::istringstream issb(b);
    int ia, ib;
    issa >> ia;
    issb >> ib;
    if (ia != ib)
        return ia < ib;

    // Numbers are the same --> remove numbers and recurse
    std::string anew, bnew;
    std::getline(issa, anew);
    std::getline(issb, bnew);
    return (compareNat(anew, bnew));
}
```

`toUpper()` function:

```
std::string toUpper(std::string s){
    for(int i=0;i<(int)s.length();i++){s[i]=toupper(s[i]);}
    return s;
    }
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<std::string> str;
str.push_back("abc1def");
str.push_back("abc10def");
...
std::sort(str.begin(), str.end(), compareNat);
```

Comment: This is not very efficient, a more efficient and comprehensive solution is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33880554/3744681)

Answer (score 0):

To solve what is essentially a parsing problem a state machine (aka [finite state automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)) is the way to go. Dissatisfied with the above solutions i wrote a simple one-pass early bail-out algorithm that beats C/C++ variants suggested above in terms of performance, does not suffer from numerical datatype overflow errors, and is easy to modify to add case insensitivity if required.

sources can be found [here](https://www.o-rho.com/naturalsort)

Comment: Please post your code here instead of ask them to go to your personal website.

Comment: my personal website is where it is maintained, and where it will be. glad i could be of help to others.

Comment: @Jan-MartenSpit your website is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

For those that arrive here and are already using Qt in their project, you can use the `QCollator` class. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933883/sort-filenames-naturally-with-qt) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Avalanchesort is a recursive variation of naturall sort, whiche merge runs, while exploring the stack of sorting-datas. The algorithim will sort stable, even if you add datas to your sorting-heap, while the algorithm is running/sorting.

The search-principle is simple. **Only merge runs with the same rank.**

After finding the first two naturell runs (rank 0), avalanchesort merge them to a run with rank 1. Then it call avalanchesort, to generate a second run with rank 1 and merge the two runs to a run with rank 2. Then it call the avalancheSort to generate a run with rank 2 on the unsorted datas....

My Implementation [porthd/avalanchesort](https://github.com/porthd/avalanchesort) divide the sorting from the handling of the data using interface injection. You can use the algorithmn for datastructures like array, associative arrays or lists.

```
    /**
 * @param DataListAvalancheSortInterface $dataList
 * @param DataRangeInterface $beginRange
 * @param int $avalancheIndex
 * @return bool
 */
public function startAvalancheSort(DataListAvalancheSortInterface $dataList)
{
    $avalancheIndex = 0;
    $rangeResult = $this->avalancheSort($dataList, $dataList->getFirstIdent(), $avalancheIndex);
    if (!$dataList->isLastIdent($rangeResult->getStop())) {
        do {
            $avalancheIndex++;
            $lastIdent = $rangeResult->getStop();
            if ($dataList->isLastIdent($lastIdent)) {
                $rangeResult = new $this->rangeClass();
                $rangeResult->setStart($dataList->getFirstIdent());
                $rangeResult->setStop($dataList->getLastIdent());
                break;
            }
            $nextIdent = $dataList->getNextIdent($lastIdent);
            $rangeFollow = $this->avalancheSort($dataList, $nextIdent, $avalancheIndex);
            $rangeResult = $this->mergeAvalanche($dataList, $rangeResult, $rangeFollow);
        } while (true);
    }
    return $rangeResult;
}

/**
 * @param DataListAvalancheSortInterface $dataList
 * @param DataRangeInterface $range
 * @return DataRangeInterface
 */
protected function findRun(DataListAvalancheSortInterface $dataList,
                           $startIdent)
{
    $result = new $this->rangeClass();
    $result->setStart($startIdent);
    $result->setStop($startIdent);
    do {
        if ($dataList->isLastIdent($result->getStop())) {
            break;
        }
        $nextIdent = $dataList->getNextIdent($result->getStop());
        if ($dataList->oddLowerEqualThanEven(
            $dataList->getDataItem($result->getStop()),
            $dataList->getDataItem($nextIdent)
        )) {
            $result->setStop($nextIdent);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
    return $result;
}

/**
 * @param DataListAvalancheSortInterface $dataList
 * @param $beginIdent
 * @param int $avalancheIndex
 * @return DataRangeInterface|mixed
 */
protected function avalancheSort(DataListAvalancheSortInterface $dataList,
                                 $beginIdent,
                                 int $avalancheIndex = 0)
{
    if ($avalancheIndex === 0) {
        $rangeFirst = $this->findRun($dataList, $beginIdent);
        if ($dataList->isLastIdent($rangeFirst->getStop())) {
            // it is the last run
            $rangeResult = $rangeFirst;
        } else {
            $nextIdent = $dataList->getNextIdent($rangeFirst->getStop());
            $rangeSecond = $this->findRun($dataList, $nextIdent);
            $rangeResult = $this->mergeAvalanche($dataList, $rangeFirst, $rangeSecond);
        }
    } else {
        $rangeFirst = $this->avalancheSort($dataList,
            $beginIdent,
            ($avalancheIndex - 1)
        );
        if ($dataList->isLastIdent($rangeFirst->getStop())) {
            $rangeResult = $rangeFirst;
        } else {
            $nextIdent = $dataList->getNextIdent($rangeFirst->getStop());
            $rangeSecond = $this->avalancheSort($dataList,
                $nextIdent,
                ($avalancheIndex - 1)
            );
            $rangeResult = $this->mergeAvalanche($dataList, $rangeFirst, $rangeSecond);
        }
    }
    return $rangeResult;
}

protected function mergeAvalanche(DataListAvalancheSortInterface $dataList, $oddListRange, $evenListRange)
{
    $resultRange = new $this->rangeClass();
    $oddNextIdent = $oddListRange->getStart();
    $oddStopIdent = $oddListRange->getStop();
    $evenNextIdent = $evenListRange->getStart();
    $evenStopIdent = $evenListRange->getStop();
    $dataList->initNewListPart($oddListRange, $evenListRange);
    do {
        if ($dataList->oddLowerEqualThanEven(
            $dataList->getDataItem($oddNextIdent),
            $dataList->getDataItem($evenNextIdent)
        )) {
            $dataList->addListPart($oddNextIdent);
            if ($oddNextIdent === $oddStopIdent) {
                $restTail = $evenNextIdent;
                $stopTail = $evenStopIdent;
                break;
            }
            $oddNextIdent = $dataList->getNextIdent($oddNextIdent);
        } else {
            $dataList->addListPart($evenNextIdent);
            if ($evenNextIdent === $evenStopIdent) {
                $restTail = $oddNextIdent;
                $stopTail = $oddStopIdent;
                break;
            }
            $evenNextIdent = $dataList->getNextIdent($evenNextIdent);

        }
    } while (true);
    while ($stopTail !== $restTail) {
        $dataList->addListPart($restTail);
        $restTail = $dataList->getNextIdent($restTail);
    }
    $dataList->addListPart($restTail);
    $dataList->cascadeDataListChange($resultRange);
    return $resultRange;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My algorithm with test code of java version. If you want to use it in your project you can define a comparator yourself.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class FileNameSortTest {

    private static List<String> names = Arrays.asList(
            "A__01__02",
            "A__2__02",
            "A__1__23",
            "A__11__23",
            "A__3++++",
            "B__1__02",
            "B__22_13",
            "1_22_2222",
            "12_222_222",
            "2222222222",
            "1.sadasdsadsa",
            "11.asdasdasdasdasd",
            "2.sadsadasdsad",
            "22.sadasdasdsadsa",
            "3.asdasdsadsadsa",
            "adsadsadsasd1",
            "adsadsadsasd10",
            "adsadsadsasd3",
            "adsadsadsasd02"
    );

    public static void main(String...args) {
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        names.forEach(s -> {
            File f = new File(s);
            try {
                if (!f.exists()) {
                    f.createNewFile();
                }
                files.add(f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        files.sort(Comparator.comparing(File::getName));
        files.forEach(f -> System.out.print(f.getName() + " "));
        System.out.println();

        files.sort(new Comparator<File>() {

            boolean caseSensitive = false;
            int SPAN_OF_CASES = 'a' - 'A';

            @Override
            public int compare(File left, File right) {
                char[] csLeft = left.getName().toCharArray(), csRight = right.getName().toCharArray();
                boolean isNumberRegion = false;
                int diff=0, i=0, j=0, lenLeft=csLeft.length, lenRight=csRight.length;
                char cLeft = 0, cRight = 0;
                for (; i<lenLeft && j<lenRight; i++, j++) {
                    cLeft = getCharByCaseSensitive(csLeft[i]);
                    cRight = getCharByCaseSensitive(csRight[j]);
                    boolean isNumericLeft = isNumeric(cLeft), isNumericRight = isNumeric(cRight);
                    if (isNumericLeft && isNumericRight) {
                        // Number start!
                        if (!isNumberRegion) {
                            isNumberRegion = true;
                            // Remove prefix '0'
                            while (i < lenLeft && cLeft == '0') i++;
                            while (j < lenRight && cRight == '0') j++;
                            if (i == lenLeft || j == lenRight) break;
                        }
                        // Diff start: calculate the diff value.
                        if (cLeft != cRight && diff == 0)
                            diff = cLeft - cRight;
                    } else {
                        if (isNumericLeft != isNumericRight) {
                            // One numeric and one char.
                            if (isNumberRegion)
                                return isNumericLeft ? 1 : -1;
                            return cLeft - cRight;
                        } else {
                            // Two chars: if (number) diff don't equal 0 return it.
                            if (diff != 0)
                                return diff;
                            // Calculate chars diff.
                            diff = cLeft - cRight;
                            if (diff != 0)
                                return diff;
                            // Reset!
                            isNumberRegion = false;
                            diff = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // The longer one will be put backwards.
                return (i == lenLeft && j == lenRight) ? cLeft - cRight : (i == lenLeft ? -1 : 1) ;
            }

            private boolean isNumeric(char c) {
                return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
            }

            private char getCharByCaseSensitive(char c) {
                return caseSensitive ? c : (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ? (char) (c + SPAN_OF_CASES) : c);
            }
        });
        files.forEach(f -> System.out.print(f.getName() + " "));
    }
}
```

The output is,

```
1.sadasdsadsa 11.asdasdasdasdasd 12_222_222 1_22_2222 2.sadsadasdsad 22.sadasdasdsadsa 2222222222 3.asdasdsadsadsa A__01__02 A__11__23 A__1__23 A__2__02 A__3++++ B__1__02 B__22_13 adsadsadsasd02 adsadsadsasd1 adsadsadsasd10 adsadsadsasd3 
1.sadasdsadsa 1_22_2222 2.sadsadasdsad 3.asdasdsadsadsa 11.asdasdasdasdasd 12_222_222 22.sadasdasdsadsa 2222222222 A__01__02 A__1__23 A__2__02 A__3++++ A__11__23 adsadsadsasd02 adsadsadsasd1 adsadsadsasd3 adsadsadsasd10 B__1__02 B__22_13 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// -1: s0 < s1; 0: s0 == s1; 1: s0 > s1
static int numericCompare(const string &s0, const string &s1) {
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    for (; i < s0.size() && j < s1.size();) {
        string t0(1, s0[i++]);
        while (i < s0.size() && !(isdigit(t0[0]) ^ isdigit(s0[i]))) {
            t0.push_back(s0[i++]);
        }
        string t1(1, s1[j++]);
        while (j < s1.size() && !(isdigit(t1[0]) ^ isdigit(s1[j]))) {
            t1.push_back(s1[j++]);
        }
        if (isdigit(t0[0]) && isdigit(t1[0])) {
            size_t p0 = t0.find_first_not_of('0');
            size_t p1 = t1.find_first_not_of('0');
            t0 = p0 == string::npos ? "" : t0.substr(p0);
            t1 = p1 == string::npos ? "" : t1.substr(p1);
            if (t0.size() != t1.size()) {
                return t0.size() < t1.size() ? -1 : 1;
            }
        }
        if (t0 != t1) {
            return t0 < t1 ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
    return i == s0.size() && j == s1.size() ? 0 : i != s0.size() ? 1 : -1;
}
```

I am not very sure if it is you want, anyway, you can have a try:-)

Comment: This returns 0 for `numericCompare("z01", "z1")`, which doesn't seem desirable.

Comment: This algorithm uses extra memory: temporary strings.
At least, you could use ranges (pairs of iterators) instead.