# How does strings comparison in C++ work?

Tags: c++, string, palindrome

I am trying to solve [this problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/).

I am implementing it with strings. Here is my code snippet

```
string s,ss;
// s and ss both contains integer input.

while(s <= ss )
//while( s<=ss && s.size() <= ss.size())
{
    int i = inc, j = dec;   // inc and dec are middle values. both equal if odd else different

    while((s[j]-'0')==9 && i < len && j>=0){
        // for cases like 999
        s[i] = s[j] = '0';
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    if(j<0){
        s = "1" + s;
        int l = s[len-1] - '0';
        l++;
        //cout<<l<<"\n";
        s[len] = (l + '0');
    }
    else{
        int l = s[j] - '0';
        l++;
        s[i] = s[j] = (l+'0');
    }

    if(s <= ss)
        cout<<"out in wild "<<s<<" and "<<ss<<"\n";
}

cout<<s<<endl;
```

The problem that I am facing is when input is like 999 or 9999. The outer while loop keeps on looping even when the value of `s` increases, but if I add `while( s<=ss && s.size() <= ss.size())` it works completely fine. Why is while(s<=ss) is not working? I rarely use the `string` class, so I don't understand it completely. Why don't `string s= 101` and `ss=99` stop the while loop?

Complete code link is [here](http://ur1.ca/hz9km)

Comment: It uses a lexicographical comparison, as [any reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) would tell you. `"101"` is "less" than `"99"`.

Comment: string compare is lexicographical, so "101" is less than "99" because "1" precedes "9".

Comment: One suggestion, you can improve your code by using some meaningful variable names instead of `s`, `l`, `ss`.

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing strings with [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), not numbers , so "101" is less than "99" (because '1' < '9') , e.g.

```
int main(){
    std::string s = "99";
    std::string ss = "101";
    
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (s <= ss);  
}
```

Outputs `false`.

**Notes:**

- A better design for your program would be to manipulate numbers (`int` or `double` ...) and not strings in the first place, so this kind of expressions would naturally work as you expect.

  E.g. "101" + "99" is "10199", not "200" ...
- But if you really need strings, consider [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622516/sorting-stdstrings-with-numbers-in-them) to sort strings containing numbers.
- As pointed by @Deduplicator, a program that needlessly overuses strings is sometimes called [Stringly Typed](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped)
- Also see [`std::lexicographical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare)

---

Since your input explicitly only involves **positive integers without leading 0**, writing a comparison function is trivial, something like : (untested)

```
/* Returns 1 if the integer represented by s1 > the integer represented by s2
*  Returns -1 if the integer represented by s1 < the integer represented by s2
*  Return 0 is both are equals
*
*  s1 and s2 must be strings representing positive integers without trailing 0
*/
int compare(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
  if(s1.size() > s2.size())
      return 1;
  if(s2.size() > s1.size())
      return -1;
      
  for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < s1.size() ; ++i)
  {
    if(s1[i] - '0' < s2[i] - '0')
      return 1;
    if(s2[i] - '0' < s1[i] - '0')
      return -1;
  }
          
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this question can't be implemented with int or double or any other variables because the input limit is 1000000 digits. I need to use array or string.

Comment: @anonghost See my second note, I added a link to compare strings containing numbers

Answer (score 0):

While *s* and *ss* are string variables, they are compared character by character.

In the case that you mentioned being: `s = "101"` & `ss = "99"`, by first hand it will check the first character in each string, and as `'1' < '9'` it exit up with *s* < *ss*. I would advise you to convert those values to integers before comparison.

Comment: thank you for explaining it in such a simple way. I think in string '1' it will be 49 and for '9' is (48+9) but i get the idea. Some link please.

Answer (score 0):

As the s is compared with ss in lexicographical order, I would suggest you to compare one char from tail with one char from head (one by one till you reach the middle) to solve that problem.