# Sort filenames naturally with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, natural-sort

I am reading a directories content using `QDir::entryList()`. The filenames within are structured like this:

```
index_randomNumber.png
```

I need them sorted by `index`, the way the Windows Explorer would sort the files so that I get

```
0_0815.png
1_4711.png
2_2063.png
...
```

instead of what the sorting by `QDir::Name` gives me:

```
0_0815.png
10000_6661.png
10001_7401.png
...
```

Is there a built-in way in Qt to achieve this and if not, what's the right place to implement it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to use [`QCollator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcollator.html) to sort entries from the list of entries returned by [`QDir::entryList`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryList), you can sort the result with [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks);
dir.setSorting(QDir::NoSort);  // will sort manually with std::sort

auto entryList = dir.entryList();

QCollator collator;
collator.setNumericMode(true);

std::sort(
    entryList.begin(),
    entryList.end(),
    [&](const QString &file1, const QString &file2)
    {
        return collator.compare(file1, file2) < 0;
    });
```

---

According to [The Badger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991000/the-badger)'s comment, `QCollator` can also be used directly as an argument to `std::sort`, replacing the lambda, so the call to `std::sort` becomes:

```
std::sort(entryList.begin(), entryList.end(), collator);
```

Comment: The lambda is actually not needed since QCollator has an undocumented `operator()`: `std::sort(entryList.begin(), entryList.end(), collator);` should be good enough. I think it is implied in the following line in the docs "A QCollator object can be used together with template based sorting algorithms such as std::sort to sort a list of QStrings."

Answer (score 13):

Qt didn't have natural sort implementation until Qt 5.2, see [this feature request](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-3316).

Since Qt 5.2 there is [QCollator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcollator.html) which allows natural sort when  [numeric mode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcollator.html#setNumericMode) is enabled.

Comment: obviously this *is* the right answer, but since Romário actually provides the code, he has to get the vote!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

In order to do that you need to specify the flag [LocaleAware](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qdir.html#SortFlag-enum) when constructing the `QDir`. object. The constructor is

```
 QDir(const QString & path, const QString & nameFilter, SortFlags sort = SortFlags( Name | IgnoreCase ), Filters filters = AllEntries)
```

You can also use

```
QDir dir;
dir.setSorting(QDir::LocaleAware);
```

Comment: Thanks, that changed the outcome, but didn't solve the problem. Now the filenames are sorted like: `0_0815, 1_4711, 10_8234, 100_5978, ... `.

Comment: You'll probably need to sort filenames yourself.

Comment: try `dir.setSorting(QDir::Name);` or `dir.setSorting(QDir::LocaleAware|QDir::Name);`. Sorry but i cannot check it now, i have to leave

Comment: @elmigranto I though so, but in general Qt gives a way to obtain the exact same results as a native app would do.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work for me. `QCollator` allows you to set the numeric mode; `QDir::setSorting()` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
inline int findNumberPart(const QString& sIn)
{
  QString s = "";
  int i = 0;
  bool isNum = false;
  while (i < sIn.length())
  {
    if (isNum)
    {
      if (!sIn[i].isNumber())
        break;
      s += sIn[i];
    }
    else
    {
      if (sIn[i].isNumber())
        s += sIn[i];
    }
    ++i;
  }
  if (s == "")
    return 0;
  return s.toInt();
}

bool naturalSortCallback(const QString& s1, const QString& s2)
{
  int idx1 = findNumberPart(s1);
  int idx2 = findNumberPart(s2);
  return (idx1 < idx2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  QDir dir(MYPATH);
  QStringList list = dir.entryList(QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
  qSort(list.begin(), list.end(), naturalSortCallback);
  foreach(QString s, list)
    qDebug() << s << endl;

  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Not sure this function will work in all cases because it's simply extracting the number from the strings without checking where the number actually is. For example, it would sort "aaa2,bbb1" as "bbb1,aaa2", which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to the question as such, but some general information for the benefit of others that stumble across this trying to figure out how to "sort naturally".

First off: it's impossible. "Correct" natural sorting depends on context that — short of "true" artificial intelligence — is virtually impossible to have. For instance, if I have a bunch of file names with mixed numbers and letters, and some parts of those names happen to match `[0-9a-f]`, is that a hexadecimal number? Is "1,500" the same as "1500", or are "1" and "500" individual numbers? Does "2019/06/07" come before or after "2019/07/06"? What about "1.21" vs. "1.5"? (Hint: the last depends on if those are decimal numbers or semantic version numbers.)

"Solving" this problem requires constraining it; deciding we're only going to handle specific cases, and anything outside of those bounds is just going to produce a "wrong" answer. (Fortunately, the OP's problem would appear to already satisfy the usual set of constraints.)

That said, I believe `QCollator` works generally well (again, in that it doesn't "really" work, but it succeeds within the constraints that are generally accepted). In the "own solutions" department, have a look also at [qtNaturalSort](https://github.com/Kitware/qtextensions/blob/master/util/qtNaturalSort.h), which I wrote as a Qt-API improvement over a different (not `QCollator`) algorithm. (Case insensitivity is not supported as of writing, but patches welcomed!) I put a whole bunch of effort into making it parse numbers "correctly", even handling numbers of arbitrary length and non-BMP digits.

Answer (score -1):

Qt doesn't support natural sorting natively, but it can be quite easily implemented. For example, this can be used to sort a `QStringList`:

```
struct naturalSortCompare {

    inline bool isNumber(QChar c) {
        return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
    }

    inline bool operator() (const QString& s1, const QString& s2) {
        if (s1 == "" || s2 == "") return s1 < s2;

        // Move to the first difference between the strings
        int startIndex = -1;
        int length = s1.length() > s2.length() ? s2.length() : s1.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            QChar c1 = s1[i];
            QChar c2 = s2[i];
            if (c1 != c2) {
                startIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If the strings are the same, exit now.
        if (startIndex < 0) return s1 < s2;

        // Now extract the numbers, if any, from the two strings.
        QString sn1;
        QString sn2;
        bool done1 = false;
        bool done2 = false;
        length = s1.length() < s2.length() ? s2.length() : s1.length();

        for (int i = startIndex; i < length; i++) {
            if (!done1 && i < s1.length()) {
                if (isNumber(s1[i])) {
                    sn1 += QString(s1[i]);
                } else {
                    done1 = true;
                }
            }

            if (!done2 && i < s2.length()) {
                if (isNumber(s2[i])) {
                    sn2 += QString(s2[i]);
                } else {
                    done2 = true;
                }
            }

            if (done1 && done2) break;
        }

        // If none of the strings contain a number, use a regular comparison.
        if (sn1 == "" && sn2 == "") return s1 < s2;

        // If one of the strings doesn't contain a number at that position,
        // we put the string without number first so that, for example,
        // "example.bin" is before "example1.bin"
        if (sn1 == "" && sn2 != "") return true;
        if (sn1 != "" && sn2 == "") return false;

        return sn1.toInt() < sn2.toInt();
    }

};
```

Then usage is simply:

```
std::sort(stringList.begin(), stringList.end(), naturalSortCompare());
```

Comment: This implementation seems to be faulty. Example input strings: `f3.ext, f10.ext, f100.ext, f1000.ext, f15.ext`. I think it is problematic that it first advanced to the point when the characters are no longer equal, because that disregards valuable numeric comparisons. I found I needed to always consume as many numbers as possible.