# How can I find the number of unique characters in a string?

Tags: c, count, character, charactercount

I have found nothing particular for this purpose.

I am trying to figure out a function that counts each of the characters' occurrences in a string, so that I can pull them out at the end from the length to find how many homogeneous characters are used in that string.

I've tried with nested loop, the first to apply and the second to scan the string and conditionally fulfill the character if it does not appear elsewhere in the string:

```
size_t CountUniqueCharacters(char *str)
{
    int i,j;
    char unique[CHAR_MAX];
    for(i=strlen(str); i>=0; i--)
    {
        for(j=strlen(str); j>=0; j--)
        {
            if(str[i] != unique[j])
                unique[j] = str[i];
        }
    }
    return strlen(unique);
}
```

This didn't work well.

This is useful if you are willing to limit someone to type lazy names such as `"aaaaaaaaaaaaa"`.

Comment: This really isn't much of a question, it's rather close to "can I have teh codez" which is not generally optimal for this forum.

Comment: I didn't asked for "teh codes" the little title cleary says what is the question. Looking for a function or method.. i haven't said i need a full code. A pseudo-code would work for me too.

Comment: I don't entirely understand the question (the second sentence makes no sense to me) - are you looking for a method that takes a string and a character and returns the number of occurrences of the character in the string?

Comment: @Daniel noo.. as the title says "all the character occurrences".
Which means something like..
`char* str = "Cannono";`
`printf("%i", ccnt(str));`
Which returns 4 because in "Cannono" we have 4 different characters.

Comment: Oh, you're looking for the number of *unique* characters in the string. What have you tried?

Comment: `for(i=strlen(str); i>=0; i--) { for(j=strlen(str); j>=0; j--) { if(str[i] != unique[j]) unique[j] = str[i]; } } return strlen(unique);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This method has `O(n^2)` complexity, but it's very possible (though a bit more complex) to do this in `O(n)`.

```
int CountUniqueCharacters(char* str){
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){
         bool appears = false;
         for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
              if (str[j] == str[i]){
                  appears = true;
                  break;
              }
         }

         if (!appears){
             count++;
         }
    }

    return count;
}
```

The method iterates over all the characters in the string - for each character, it checks if the character appeared in any of the previous characters. If it didn't, then the character is unique, and the count is incremented.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing, but with one logical mistake.. didn't put the condition inside the first loop after the second one.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple C++ solution. This method has O(n) complexity:

```
int countDistinct(string s) 
{ 

    unordered_map<char, int> m; 
  
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) { 
        m[s[i]]++; 
    } 
  
    return m.size(); 
}
```

Comment: You should analyze the complexity of `unordered_map` mechanism, so that the overall complexity does not lead to O(n), I think.

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily long, you don't need to keep track of frequencies and therefore can use a unordered_set. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69340820/3586940) below that is shorter with the same time complexity.

Answer (score 3):

I find the following way of counting distinct characters, very simple and in `O(n)`.
Here the logic is, just traverse through the character array, and for each character
make its count `1`, even if it repeats, just override the value with `1` only.
After you are done with traversing, just sum all the character occurance.

```
int count_distinc_char(const char *a){
     int c_arr[MAX_CHAR] = {0};
     int i, count = 0;
     for( i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++){
         c_arr[a[i] - 'a'] = 1;
     }    
     for( i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++){
         count += c_arr[i];
     }
     return count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

well you can use a HashSet or unordered_set for the purpose but it has a worst case time complexity of O(N). Hence, its best to use an array of 256 memory locations or `arr[256]`. This gives the desired output in O(256)~ O(1) time

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++, here's a one-liner that has optimal time complexity:

```
int numUniqeChars = std::unordered_set<char>(std::begin(str), std::end(str)).size();
```

Comment: did you meant
`int numUniqeChars = std::size(std::unordered_set<char>(std::begin(str), std::end(str)));`

Comment: @gov yeah, thanks for catching that, fixed now.

Comment: as `std::size` is not supported in c++11, you can use `std::unordered_set<char> uset(std::begin(str), std::end(str));
int numUniqeChars = uset.size();`

Comment: @gov good callout, I changed the answer to make it work on older versions of C++.

Answer (score 1):

Create a linked list to store the characters found in the string and its occurences with the node structure as follow,

```
struct tagCharOccurence 
{
    char ch;
    unsigned int iCount;
};
```

Now read all the characters in a string one by one and as you read one character check if it is present in your linked list, if yes then increase its count and if character is not found in linked list then insert a new node with 'ch' set to read character and count initialized to one.

In this way you'll get the count of occurences of each character in single pass only.
You can now use the linked list to print the characters as many times as its has been encountered.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this question while looking for some other stuff on Stack Overflow. But I still post a solution which might be helpful to some:

This is also used for implementation of huffman conding [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#C.2B.2B). There you need to know the frequency of each character, so a bit more than what you need.

```
#include <climits>
const int UniqueSymbols = 1 << CHAR_BIT;
const char* SampleString = "this is an example for huffman encoding";
```

Left shift operator shifts lhs (i.e. 1) `CHAR_BIT` times to the left, hence multiplying with 2^8 (on most computers) which is 256, as there are 256 unique symbols in UTF-8

and in your `main` you have

```
int main() {
    // Build frequency table
    int frequencies[UniqueSymbols] = {0};
    const char* ptr = SampleString;
    while (*ptr != '\0') {
        ++frequencies[*ptr++];
    }
}
```

I found it quite minimal and helpful. The only downside is that the size of `frequencies` is 256 here, uniqueness is then just checking which value is 1.

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up. This seems like a variant of a lookup table. Their downsides are usually the huge chunk of memory being used, but are quite fast and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

In this algorithm, the cost is lower and the speed is higher. Because every time a search is done in a smaller string. It also does not need compare between strings or "split" or "(list or array)".

```
QString out = "";
QString str = "Does he not know that God sees?";
while (str.size() > 0) {
   out += str[0];
   str = str.replace(str[0],"",Qt::CaseInsensitive);
}
qDebug() << out << out.size();
```

**output:** "Does hntkwaG?" 13

ignore Case Insensitive and use , between letters.

```
QString out = "";
QString str = "Does he not know that God sees?";
while (str.size() > 0) {
   out += str[0];
   if(str.size() != 1)
       out += ',';
   str = str.replace(str[0],"");
}
qDebug() << out;
```

**output:** "D,o,e,s, ,h,n,t,k,w,a,G,d,?"

To sort, refer to this link: [Sort filenames naturally with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933883/sort-filenames-naturally-with-qt/36018397#36018397)

Answer (score -1):

Here is source code of the C Program to Count the Number of Unique Words. The C program is successfully compiled and run on a Linux system

```
int i = 0, e, j, d, k, space = 0;

char a[50], b[15][20], c[15][20];



printf("Read a string:\n");

fflush(stdin);

scanf("%[^\n]s", a);

for (i = 0;a[i] != '\0';i++)        //loop to count no of words

{

    if (a[i] =  = ' ')

        space++;

}

i = 0;

for (j = 0;j<(space + 1);i++, j++)    //loop to store each word into an 2D array

{

    k = 0;

    while (a[i] != '\0')

    {

        if (a[i] == ' ')

        {

            break;

        }

        else

        {

            b[j][k++] = a[i];

            i++;

        }

    }

    b[j][k] = '\0';

}

i = 0;

strcpy(c[i], b[i]);

for (e = 1;e <= j;e++)        //loop to check whether the string is already present in the 2D array or not

{

    for (d = 0;d <= i;d++)

    {

        if (strcmp(c[i], b[e]) == 0)

            break;

        else

        {

            i++;

            strcpy(c[i], b[e]);

            break;

        }

    }

}

printf("\nNumber of unique words in %s are:%d", a, i);

return 0;
```