# (valid) QFileInfo causes segv when calling QFileInfo::filename() in std::sort

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, std, qfileinfo

I need to sort a list of files based on filename. These files are gathered from a [QDirIterator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html).

I am using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36018397/4628115). **TL;DR** - use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a [QCollator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcollator.html).

Since [QCollator::compare(QString&, QString&)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcollator.html#compare-1) uses strings, I need to get the file path or the filename *(or some unique string representation of each file to sort - I need to sort based on filename)*

**Problem:**

When sorting, I get the `QFileInfo::filename()` of each file, and attempt to sort based on this value. However, I reach a point where this causes a segv (see code below). When debugging, in an attempt to find the cause of the problem, (in my specific case) `a` reports as inaccessible (see second screenshot).

**Code for MVCE:**

```
// header
QList<QFileInfo> fileInfoImageList, fileInfoVideoList;
QDir dataDirectory; // path that contains folders of various media type

// source
QCollator collator;
collator.setNumericMode(true);
QDirIterator it(dataDirectory.path(), combinedList, QDir::Filter::Files | QDir::Filter::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Filter::NoSymLinks, QDirIterator::IteratorFlag::Subdirectories);

while (it.hasNext() && !stopIteratorLoading) {
   QFileInfo fi(it.next());

   if (isImage(fi)) {
        fileInfoImageList.append(fi);
   }
   else if (isVideo(fi)) {
        fileInfoVideoList.append(fi);
   }
}

std::sort(fileInfoImageList.begin(), fileInfoImageList.end(), [&collator](const QFileInfo & a, const QFileInfo & b) {
   QString nameA = a.fileName();     < ------------- offending line causing segv
   QString nameB = b.fileName();
   return collator.compare(nameA, nameB);
});

std::sort(fileInfoVideoList.begin(), fileInfoVideoList.end(), [&collator](const QFileInfo & a, const QFileInfo & b) {
   QString nameA = a.fileName();
   QString nameB = b.fileName();
   return collator.compare(nameA, nameB);
});

if (stopIteratorLoading) {
   return;
}

//...
```

*What I can say about the file paths is they some may extend to as far as (and possibly further than 180 characters in length, but this is less that the [maximum file path length limited by Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1880321/4628115).*

---

**Source of SEGV screenshot**
[image]

**Offending line in `std::sort` screenshot**
[image]

**Stack Trace**

> 1   QFileInfo::fileName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      qfileinfo.cpp      758  0x65a1a5a
> 2   ExplorerDialog::<lambda()>::<lambda(const QFileInfo&, const QFileInfo&)>::operator()(const QFileInfo &, const QFileInfo &) const                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ExplorerView.cpp   309  0x44f30c
> 3   __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iterExplorerDialog::refreshAggregatedFiles()::<lambda()::<lambda(const QFileInfo&, const QFileInfo&)>>::operator()<QList::iterator, QList::iterator>(QList::iterator, QList::iterator)                                                                                                                                                        predefined_ops.h   143  0x462e42
> 4   std::__unguarded_partition<QList::iterator, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iterExplorerDialog::refreshAggregatedFiles()::<lambda()::<lambda(const QFileInfo&, const QFileInfo&)>>>(QList::iterator, QList::iterator, QList::iterator, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iterExplorerDialog::refreshAggregatedFiles()::<lambda()::<lambda(const QFileInfo&, const QFileInfo&)>>) stl_algo.h         1902 0x462d2c
> 5   std::__unguarded_partition_pivot<QList::iterator, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iterExplorerDialog::refreshAggregatedFiles()::<lambda()::<lambda(const QFileInfo&, const QFileInfo&)>>>(QList::iterator, QList::iterator, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iterExplorerDialog::refreshAggregatedFiles()::<lambda()::<lambda(const QFileInfo&, const QFileInfo&)>>)                       stl_algo.h         1923 0x46198e
> 6   std::__introsort_loop<QList::iterator, int, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iterExplorerDialog::refreshAggregatedFiles()::<lambda()::<lambda(const QFileInfo&, const QFileInfo&)>>>(QList::iterator, QList::iterator, int, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iterExplorerDialog::refreshAggregatedFiles()::<lambda()::<lambda(const QFileInfo&, const QFileInfo&)>>)                        stl_algo.h         1952 0x45fed6
> 7   std::__sort<QList::iterator, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iterExplorerDialog::refreshAggregatedFiles()::<lambda()::<lambda(const QFileInfo&, const QFileInfo&)>>>(QList::iterator, QList::iterator, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iterExplorerDialog::refreshAggregatedFiles()::<lambda()::<lambda(const QFileInfo&, const QFileInfo&)>>)                                            stl_algo.h         1968 0x45eadd
> 8   std::sort<QList::iterator, ExplorerDialog::refreshAggregatedFiles()::<lambda()>::<lambda(const QFileInfo&, const QFileInfo&)>>(QList::iterator, QList::iterator, ExplorerDialog::<lambda()>::<lambda(const QFileInfo&, const QFileInfo&)>)                                                                                                                                              stl_algo.h         4868 0x45d9be
> 9   ExplorerDialog::<lambda()>::operator()(void) const                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ExplorerView.cpp   308  0x44f673
> 10  std::_Function_handler<void(), ExplorerDialog::refreshAggregatedFiles()::<lambda()>>::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data &)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  std_function.h     316  0x45ec7b
> 11  std::function<void ()>::operator()() const                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               std_function.h     706  0x525442

Comment: What is `fileInfoImageList`?

Comment: @vahancho see update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QCollater::compare(s1, s2)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcollator.html#compare-1) returns `"an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero depending on whether s1 sorts before, with or after s2"`, hence your comparator doesn't obey strict weak ordering -- it's effectively checking the relationship 's1 != s2' rather than 's1 < s2'.  That's undefined behaviour.

Try changing the sort comparator to...

```
std::sort(fileInfoImageList.begin(), fileInfoImageList.end(),
          [&collator](const QFileInfo &a, const QFileInfo &b)
          {
              QString nameA = a.fileName();
              QString nameB = b.fileName();
              return collator.compare(nameA, nameB) < 0;
          });
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it works correctly! I had it in mind to check if what `QString` implemented for its `operator <` but it had slipped my mind. However, assuming the implemented `<` operator, I would not have guessed in my wildest imagination that this was to cause a segv. If possible, could you maybe ammend your answer with an explaination for it?