# Sort String list with Numeric Values

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of string, which is most likely, but not guaranteed to contain a list of numerics, i.e.,

```
{"1", "6", "2", "21", "89"}
```

What is the way to sort the string list so that it will always appear in ascending order?

I can't parse the string to numeric first before doing the sorting simply because the string **can** contain non numeric characters. And I don't want to go through the list and check-cast each component to numerics and do the sorting. Is there already a library existing out there for this purpose?

**In the case where we have mix numerics and non-numeric string item, numeric strings always take precedence over the non numeric ones.**

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is "natural order sort".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been asked before slightly differently, but the same answer still applies, as they have a C# implementation on the same site.

SO Question: [Sort on a string that may contain a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number)

Answer provided by [ScArcher2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310/scarcher2): [The Alphanum Algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)

Answer (score 1):

You want to sort elements, just like Windows XP Explorer does with files. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/NaturalSortComparer.aspx) on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If this is C#, that's what Int32.TryParse() is for.

If this is C++, then std::string::find_first_not_of is a decent bet.  Pass it a string containing the ascii chars for the digits 0 to 9 (plus the minus and plus signs?) and if it returns -1 then it is an integer.

Comment: Nope, he want to be able to sort lists like this one: { a1, a10, a11, a2, a3 } in a natural way: { a1, a2, a3, a10, a11 }. TryParse will obviously not work.