# comparator with null values

Tags: java, comparator

We have some code which sorts a list of addresses based on the distance between their coordinates. this is done through collections.sort with a custom comparator.

However from time to time an address without coordinates is in the list causing a NullPointerException. My initial idea to fix this was to have the comparator return 0 as distance for addresses where at least one of the coordinates is null. I fear this might lead to corruption of the order the 'valid' elements in the list.

so is returning a '0' values for null data in a comparator ok, or is there a cleaner way to resolve this?

Comment: not very clear which distance you are calculating... Is each element of the list a pair of coordinates - one distance for each pair? Or are you calculating the distance of two adjacent coordinates of the list (is that meaningful)? Or is the distance calculated relative to a fixed coordinate (may change after each sort)?

Comment: Ordering on "distance between their coordinates"? Are you comparing them all against one fixed point or against each other? Because if you're comparing them against each other, then your order will be messed up, because that relation would not be transitive.

Comment: @Carlos: d'oh! You were faster ;-)

Comment: its compared against a fixed point yes

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Handle it like `null` means infinitely far away. Thus:

- `comp(1234, null) == -1`
- `comp(null, null) == 0`
- `comp(null, 1234) == 1`

With this, you get a consistent ordering.

Comment: ... or comp(null,null)==-1, dependant on whether you want two addressless entries to show up as being in the same place or not.

Comment: @izb, that violates the Comparator requirement of reflexivity.

Comment: @izb .... and could lead to anomalies such as unstable orderings, or worse, depending on the implementation details of the class that the comparator is plugged into.

Comment: Does it really matter if I change the ordering between a null an another null? They are supposed to be an identical platonic null. Doesn't it?

Comment: yes take a look at the Kevin Bourrillion's comment, that means that your comparator will not sort uniformely that means it will depend on the ordering of elements inside list.

Comment: Just calling out, in case anyone misreads a comment the way I did: @KevinBourrillion was responding to the first comment, not to @Sjoerd's selected answer -- @Sjoerd's answer is correctly reflexive. (`comp(x,x)==0` for all `x`)

Comment: Since Java 8, you can use `Comparator.nullsLast​(anotherComparator)` to create a comparator with the described behavior, without the need to have any `null` handling in `anotherComparator`.

Comment: Okay, so this is so simple, but do you know how many hours of debugging this simple answer has saved? Significantly more than the 751 rep awarded for it actually represent.

Answer (score 26):

Just to expand on Willi Schönborn's answer, I came here to say that [google-collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) is exactly what you're after here.

In the general case, you can just write your own `Comparator` to ignore nulls (assume non-null, so it can concentrate on the important logic), and then use [Ordering](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) to handle the nulls:

```
Collections.sort(addresses, Ordering.from(new AddressComparator()).nullsLast());
```

In your case, though, it's data WITHIN the Address (the Coordinates) that is being used to sort, right? google-collections is even *more* useful in this case. So you might have something more like:

```
// Seems verbose at first glance, but you'll probably find yourself reusing 
// this a lot and it will pay off quickly.
private static final Function<Address, Coordinates> ADDRESS_TO_COORDINATES = 
  new Function<Address, Coordinates>() {
      public Coordinates apply(Address in) {
          return in.getCoordinates();
      }
  };

private static final Comparator<Coordinates> COORDINATE_SORTER = .... // existing
```

then when you want to sort:

```
Collections.sort(addresses,
    Ordering.from(COORDINATE_SORTER)
            .nullsLast()
            .onResultOf(ADDRESS_TO_COORDINATES));
```

and that's where the power of google-collections really starts to pay off.

Comment: Note you could have made COORDINATE_SORTED extend Ordering in the first place and skipped the Ordering.from().

Comment: You can even use another .nullsLast() with `Ordering.from(COORDINATE_SORTER).nullsLast().onResultOf(ADDRESS_TO_COORDINATES).nullsLast()` to allow null adresses in the list. Does probably not make sense for the question, but might make sense in general.

Comment: In Java 8, Guava's `Ordering` class [has been made obsolete](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) by inclusion of some of the same methods in the standard Java `Comparator` class.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Java 8, you have 2 new static methods in the Comparator class, which come in handy:

```
public static <T> Comparator<T> nullsFirst(Comparator<? super T> comparator)
public static <T> Comparator<T> nullsLast(Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

The comparison will be null safe and you can choose where to place the null values in the sorted sequence.

The following example:

```
List<String> monkeyBusiness = Arrays.asList("Chimp", "eat", "sleep", "", null, "banana",
            "throw banana peel", null, "smile", "run");
Comparator<? super String> comparator = (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b);
monkeyBusiness.stream().sorted(Comparator.nullsFirst(comparator))
            .forEach(x -> System.out.print("[" + x + "] "));
```

will print:
[null] [null] [] [Chimp] [banana] [eat] [run] [sleep] [smile] [throw banana peel]

Answer (score 10):

My take on this is that anything you try to do to "make good" the `null` coordinates is just papering over the cracks.  What you really need to do is find and fix the bugs that are injecting the spurious `null` coordinates.

In my experience, infestations of NPE bugs are frequently caused by the following bad coding habits:

- inadequate validation of input parameters,
- using `null` to avoid creating empty arrays or collections,
- returning `null` when an exception should have been thrown, or
- using `null` to represent "no value" when there is a better solution.

(Better solutions to the "no value" problem typically involve rewriting code so that you don't *need* to represent this and/or using a non-null value instead; e.g. an empty String, a special instance, a reserved value.  You can't always find a better solution, but you often can.)

If this describes your application, you should be spending your time trying to find and correct the code problems that are injecting the `null` values rather than thinking of ways to avoid the NPEs they cause.

Comment: Unless a null coordinate is a valid value.

Comment: @SteveKuo - In that case you'd do better replacing it with reference to an `Coordinate` instance that means "unknown coordinates".

Comment: (Or what ever a "null coordinate" actually means.)

Answer (score 9):

My solution (might be useful for someone looking here) is to do the comparison normal, with null values replaced not by 0, but the maximum value possible (e.g. Integer.MAX_VALUE). Returning 0 is not consistent, if you have values that are themselves 0. Here a correct example:

```
        public int compare(YourObject lhs, YourObject rhs) {
            Integer l = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            Integer r = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            if (lhs != null) {
                l = lhs.giveMeSomeMeasure();
            }
            if (rhs != null) {
                r = rhs.giveMeSomeMeasure();
            }
            return l.compareTo(r);
        }
```

I just wanted to add that you don't necessary need the max value for integer. It depends of what your giveMeSomeMeasure() method can return. If for example you compare Celsius degrees for weather, you can set l and r to -300 or +300, depending where you want to set the null objects - to the head or the tail of the list.

Answer (score 4):

I know... I know... This post is quite old and already answered alot. But Guavas `Ordering` is obsolete and Java 8's `Comparator` has built in functionality to solve a lot of custom comparison stuff.

Also I wanted to add my approach in case anybody has a similar need for comparing objects via multiple fields in the object, which can be null.

## Setup

Let's work with example data of the question.
We have a list of `Address` which contains `Coordinate` data, which can be null in some situations.

## Custom Comparator

Let's asume we sort the list in a class `AddressSorter` and we only want to separate the sorting for concrete objects from those that are null. We can achieve this by using a custom `Comparator` that makes basic null checking.

```java
public class AddressSorter {
    private static final Comparator<Coordinate> COORDINATE_NULL_COMPARATOR = (c1, c2) -> {
        if (c1 != null && c2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (c1 == null && c2 != null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public List<Address> sortAddressList(List<Address> addresses) {
        return addresses.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.compare(Address::getCoordinate, COORDINATE_NULL_COMPARATOR))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

In this example we use the built in [`Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor, Comparator<? super U> keyComparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-)

This will construct a list where the `Address`es with `null` as `Coordinate` are at the beginning of the returned list.

**This will skip any comparison between any two concrete `Coordinate` completely**

This may look odd, but there are occasions where it is valid to skip the object comparison. For example any `LocalDateTime` (or any other timely object) comparison with additional chaining will result in unexpected behaviour if you need to separate the objects by a `LocalDateTime`field that can be null.

## Compare `Coordinate` with null safety

So if you need the comparison of the `Coordinate` objects including null-safety you can use the natural order with a null check like this:

```java
    public List<Address> sortAddressList(List<Address> addresses) {
        return addresses.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.compare(Address::getCoordinate, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Edit: It is also possible to use `nullsLast` if you want the `Address`es with `Coordinate == null` at the end of your list.

## Chaining

With that we can also start to chain sortings base on multiple fields of our `Address`es, e.g.:

```java
    public List<Address> sortAddressList(List<Address> addresses) {
        return addresses.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.compare(Address::getCoordinate, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                .thenCompare(Address::getId))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

So you will end up with a list where the leading `Address`es are the once containing `null` as `Coordinate` sorted by `id` and after that all `Address`es with a concrete `Coordinate` also sorted by `id`.

## Comparable and Apache Commons

If you want this behaviour as natural order for `Address` you can make `Address` implement `Comparable` and then work for example with Apache Commons `CompareToBuilder`:

```java
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Address address) {
        return new CompareToBuilder()
            .append(this.coordinate, address.coordinate, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .append(this.id, address.id)
            .toComparison();
```

This then enables you to use `sorted()` in the stream, as it makes use of the `compareTo` of `Address`:

```java
    public List<Address> sortAddressList(List<Address> addresses) {
        return addresses.stream()
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: better put as `if else` condition instead of all `if`

Answer (score 3):

You probably dont want to return 0 as that implies the addresses are equidistant and you really dont know. This is quite a classic problem where you are trying to deal with bad input data. I dont think its the responsibility of the comparator to try and determin how far the address is in realtive terms when you ***dont know*** the distance. I would remove those addresses from the list before sorting.

The hack would be to move them to the bottom of the list (but thats ugly !)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no cleaner way. Perhaps:

- if the coordinates of both compared objects are null, return 0
- if the coordinates of one of the objects are null, return -1 / 1 (depending on whether it's the first or the second argument)

But more importantly - try to get rid of / fill in the missing coordinates, or, better: don't put addresses with missing coordinates in the list.

Actually, not putting them in the list is the most logical behaviour. If you put them in the list, the result won't be actually ordered by distance.

You may create another list, containing the addresses with missing coordinates, and make it clear to whoever needs that information (end-user, API user), that the first list only contains addresses with the needed data, while the second list contains addresses that lack required information.

Comment: A method can't return -1/1 or true

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking at this like it's a technical problem with the comparator, it's better to take a look at the requirements again: what you're really trying to do here, what are you going to do with this sorted list?

- If you are trying to sort them to show the most relevant solutions first to a user, it might be a good idea to put the unknown locations last, so treat it like infinity (returning 0/-1/1 depending on which of them is null).
- If you are going to use this result to draw some graph or do some other calculations that depend on them really being sorted by their distance, then the nulls probably shouldn't have been in there anyways (so either remove them first, or throw an exception if at that point there actually weren't supposed to be any addresses with a null location).

As you already realize, always returning 0 when one of them is null is not a good idea here; it can corrupt the result indeed. But what you should do instead depends on what you need, not on what others usually do/need. How your program behaves with addresses that don't have a location (so what the user is going to see) should not depend on some technical detail like what the "best practice" for comparators is.
(To me, asking what the "best practice" is here, sounds like asking what the "best requirements" are).

Answer (score 1):

I personally hate dealing with special null cases everywhere in my comparators so i was looking for a cleaner soluation and finally found google collections. Their Ordering is just awesome. They support compound comparators, offer to sort nulls to the top and to the end and allow to run certain functions before comparing. Writing comparators has never been so easy. You should give it a try.