# How to handle null compare method arguments in Comparator?

Tags: java, libgdx, comparator

I have created an implementation of `Comparator<Entity>`, but when I use this comparator to sort an `Array<Entity>`. I will receive an `java.lang.NullPointerException`, because when I map the entity to a static collections which is already removed. Now my problem is I don't know what to return to skip the compare method.

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Entity> {

   public int compare(Entity e1, Entity e2) {
       if( e1== null || e2 == null) {
           return // don't know what to return to skip this method;
       }

       Vector2 e1Pos = Mapper.transform.get(e1).position;
       Vector2 e2Pos = Mapper.transform.get(e2).position;

   }

}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401606/comparator-with-null-values

Comment: This can only happen if your `Array` contains null elements. Solution: don't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't "skip" the comparison. What would you expect the sorting code to do? You've got to provide it with a result.

Two options are common:

- Throw a `NullPointerException` to indicate that you just don't support comparing `null` values. That's explicitly an option in the [`compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) documentation
- Decide that `null` comes before everything else, but is equal to itself

The latter implementation would be something like:

```
public int compare(Entity e1, Entity e2) {
    if (e1 == e2) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (e1 == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (e2 == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    Vector2 e1Pos = Mapper.transform.get(e1).position;
    Vector2 e2Pos = Mapper.transform.get(e2).position;
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: can you provide description what does 0, -1, 1 means? thank you it helps a lot!

Comment: @RonJuneLopez: Did you read the documentation? If so, which part of that description of the return value didn't make sense? It's hard to give a second explanation without knowing what part of the first explanation doesn't make sense for you - and the documentation should **always** be the first place you look.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Jon's answer, and answer Ron's question, one should always look at the spec before deciding what to do. In this case it says "Unlike Comparable, a comparator may optionally permit comparison of null arguments, while maintaining the requirements for an equivalence relation." See [the comparator API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). It elaborates on what is meant. I can't see any other reasonable solution.