# Sort array first by length then alphabetically in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How can I sort an array first by length, then alphabetically?

I have a list of things with numbers on them, and I am currently getting:

Something1
Something10
Something2
Something3

Whereas I want to get:

Something1 Something2 Something3 Something10

Comment: By any chance, homework?

Comment: Have a look at the answers for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number if what you really want is a sort that understands the number part.

Comment: Nope, just have a ton of files I wanted to rename really quickly. They are numbered, but the numbers need to be shifted by a bit and the rest of the file name changed around. But the natural ordering by the operating system generally returns 1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2 20 etc.

Comment: Having you tried just using leading zeroes in your numbers? IE, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>{
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {  
      if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
         return 1;
      } else if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
         return -1;
      }
      return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new MyComparator());
```

Comment: Comparator requires int compareTo(Obj o), not compare(Object o1, Object o2). This code is close though.

Comment: @Starkey: That's Comparable.  This is Comparator.  You were close though.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to sort some file names that had numbers in them really quickly and rename them.

I had them in an Array so I had to convert it to a Collection, but this worked for my purpose. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark Peters What about Comparatee?

Comment: nice way of sorting +  @KeatsPeeks

Answer (score 10):

Here's a concise Java 8 solution:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Something1", "Something10", "Something2", "Something3");
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length).thenComparing(String::compareTo));
```

Or, case-insensitive version:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length).thenComparing(String::compareToIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a Comparator which compares by length first and if the lengths are the same, uses the String.compareTo().

Comment: Also note the existence of `compareToIgnoreCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting first by length and then lexically will work ONLY if the string prefixes (i.e. the part before the number) is the same length in all cases.  I believe you may really want to write a comparator that separates the string and numeric parts and sorts alphabetically on the string and numerically on the number part.

Answer (score 0):

Define a class to hold your item in. Seems like you want it to be a String.

For that class, you need to define the Comparable interface and put the logic to compare in its abstract method.

```
int compareTo(T o)
```

For example:

```
class MyString extends String
{
  @Override
  int compareTo(Object obj)
  {
    // put your logic in here. 
    // Return -1 if this is "less than" obj. 
    // Return 0 if this is equal to obj
    // Return 1 if this is "greater than" obj.

    // Test length first
    if (length() < obj.length())
      return -1;
    if (length() > obj.length())
      return 1;

    // Lengths are the same, use the alphabetical compare defined by String already
    return super.compareTo(obj);
   }
}
```

Disclaimer, I didn't actually test this code, but it should be close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

By using lambda, The java program looking like.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String str = "This is am example";
        List<String> strl = Arrays.asList(str.split(" "));
        strl.sort( (o1,o2)->{
            if(o1.length() > o2.length())      return 1;
            else if(o1.length() < o2.length()) return -1;
            else                               return o1.compareTo(o2);
        });
        System.out.println(strl);

    }
}
```