# Sorting array not working

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       
   String[] errorStr = new String[] {
       "Line No: " + " " + 1,
       "Line No: " + " " + 11,
       "Line No: " + " " + 10,
       "Line No: " + " " + 2,
       "Line No: " + " " + 3
   };

   Arrays.sort(errorStr);       
   for(Object obj : errorStr){
       System.out.println(obj);
   }
}
```

Can someone point why the sorting is not working here?

```
expected is,

Line No: 1
Line No: 2
Line No: 3
Line No: 10
Line No: 11

Actual is, 
Line No: 1
Line No: 11
Line No: 10
Line No: 2
Line No: 3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's sorting in lexicographic order - and lexicographically "11" comes before "2", and "Line No: 11" comes before "Line No: 2".

If you want "smarter" sorting, you'll need to implement a `Comparer<String>` which performs appropriate parsing in order to compare strings.

If all your values are *actually* "Line No: " followed by a value, I'd just transform them into an array or list of integers, as that's the *natural* data you're trying to represent... and sorting an array of `int` values will work as you expect.

Fundamentally, this is what you get for treating numbers as strings :)

Comment: Alternately, write a special class that holds the line number in an appropriate `int` field and implements `Comparable`, and sort those before converting them to `String`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: See my edit - it looks like a simple transform to a collection of integers would be more appropriate to me :)

Comment: See:  [sort on a string that may contain a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number)

Answer (score 2):

As Jon said, it's sorting the elements lexicographically. You could try making an int array with the desired numbers, sorting that, and then concatenating "Line No: " to each element. I guess the solution strategy kind of depends on how the elements got out of order in the first place...

Edit: heres the code sample

```
    int[] errorInt = new int[]{ 1,11,10,2,3} ;
    String[] errorString = new String[ errorInt.length ];
    Arrays.sort(errorInt);
    for( int i = 0; i < errorInt.length; i++) {
        errorString[i] = "Error No:" + errorInt[i];
    }
```

Comment: i am having similar issue, your solution sounds like it may work for me.  Do you have a really quick and dirty example you can edit in?