# How can I sort strings with numbers in them naturally?

Tags: java, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort on a string that may contain a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number)

I'm implementing a custom sorting algorithm for a homework assignment, and I want it to sort strings with numbers attached at the end in proper order... As it is right now, "Book1" is coming after "Book10".

I'm using String.compareTo() to get the ordering, but I don't see a version of compareTo() that lets me choose any special kind of ordering.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to write your own comparator for that.

Comment: You need to implement a custom comparator which breaks up your string into parts which you expect to be compared as if they were fields.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own implementation of [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that:

- Splits the leading string from the trailing number.
- Compares the leading strings for equality.
- If equal, compares the trailing numbers for equality.

Comment: Why compare only for equality?

Comment: Because if the strings aren't equal, you can return from the comparator with a +1 or a -1.

Comment: That's why I said. You don't just need to compare for equality. But `<` and `>` also. Well this is really not so much of a concern. I just pointed out. :)

Comment: True.  You would use the String compareTo method.  For the number, you'd have to make at least two tests (< and >).