# Complex sorting of Java ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, alphanumeric

I have the following strings stored in `trendList` variable. I do a sort, but the data doesn't come out sorted properly.

i.e. `ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P1:8` should come before  `ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P10:8`

since `1 < 10`, and so on with the rest of the strings.

Question: How do I do this alphanumeric sorting to get the correct order?

Do I have to make my own function? What would that look like?

```
List<String> trendList = new ArrayList<String>(80000);

Collections.sort(trendList);

ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P0:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P10:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P11:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P12:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P13:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P14:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P15:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P1:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P2:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P3:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P4:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P5:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P6:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P7:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P8:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P9:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P0:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P10:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P11:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P12:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P13:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P14:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P15:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P1:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P2:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P3:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P4:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P5:8
MLC_C_SAMPLE
MLC_SAMPLE
SWR
TOUCHDOWN
TEST_REV
```

Comment: You could write a regex and use a custom string comparator on the numbers. However, it would make more sense to implement an object that parses these strings and implement a custom `compareTo()` method or `Comparator` on the objects.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that result because it's comparing the strings using just the default String.compareTo, which uses the raw character codes.  ':' appears after '0'-'9' so it collates afterward.

You'll need to supply your own `Comparator` and call

```
Collections.sort(trendList, new CustomComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this with your own Comparator:

```
class TrendListComparator implements Comparator<String> {
     // retrieve the P and S
     final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*_S(\\d+)_P(\\d+).*");
     public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
         Matcher m1 = p.matcher(str1);
         Matcher m2 = p.matcher(str2);
         if (m1.matches() && m2.matches()) {
             Integer s1 = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
             Integer p1 = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
             Integer s2 = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
             Integer p2 = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
             // compare
             return s1.equals(s2) ? p1.compareTo(p2) : s1.compareTo(s2);
         } else {
             return str1.compareTo(str2); // standard sort if no P and S
         }
     }
}

Collections.sort(trendList, new TrendListComparator());
```

You can see a running example here: http://ideone.com/AleOEy

You can even do it with only one Matcher and reuse it all along during the same sort:

```
class TrendListComparator implements Comparator<String> {
     // retrieve the P and S
     final Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*_S(\\d+)_P(\\d+).*_S(\\d+)_P(\\d+).*").matcher("");
     public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
         if (m.reset(str1 + str2).matches()) {
             Integer s1 = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
             Integer p1 = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
             Integer s2 = Integer.valueOf(m.group(3));
             Integer p2 = Integer.valueOf(m.group(4));
             // compare
             return s1.equals(s2) ? p1.compareTo(p2) : s1.compareTo(s2);
         } else {
             return str1.compareTo(str2); // standard sort if no P and S
         }
     }
}
```

See: http://ideone.com/EsfFPj

Comment: Hey, I really like this code but how would error checking occur? Like checking to see if there is an integer in the string? I keep getting "errored" out!

Comment: @user1022944 You can see a running example here: http://ideone.com/AleOEy

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class that implements the [`Comparator<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.  In the `compare` method, you will need to parse your string and extract the numbers from the relevant parts of the string that need to be sorted by numbers.  The method should return a number less than 0 if s1 is less than s2, 0 if s1 is equal to s2, and greater than 0 if s1 is greater than s2.

```
public class MyTrendListComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
    public int compare(String s1, String s2)
    {
        // Parse and compare here.
    }
}
```

Then pass an instance of your comparator to `Collections.sort`:

```
Collections.sort(trendList, new MyTrendListComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom comparator in to the `Collections.sort()` function:

```
Collections.sort(trendList, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int sValue1 = s1.split(...) // split the strings to retrieve their values
        int sValue2 = // ...
        int pValue1 = // ...
        int pValue2 = // ...
        if (sValue1 > sValue2) { return 1; }
        if (sValue1 < sValue2) { return -1; }
        if (pValue1 > pValue2) { return 1; }
        if (pValue 1 < pValue2) { return -1; }
        return 0;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomSorter {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      String[] data = {
         "ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P0:8",
         "ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P10:8",
         ...
         "ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P4:8",
         "ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P5:8",
      };
      List<String> trendList = Arrays.asList( data );
      Collections.sort( trendList, new Comparator< String >(){
         @Override public int compare( String o1, String o2 ){
            String[] p1 = o1.split( "_S\\d+_P" );
            String[] p2 = o2.split( "_S\\d+_P" );
            if( p1.length != 2 ) {
               throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected item: '"+o1+"'");
            }
            if( p2.length != 2 ) {
               throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected item: '"+o1+"'");
            }
            final int i1;
            try{
               i1 = Integer.parseInt(p1[1].substring(0,p1[1].indexOf(':')));
            } catch( NumberFormatException x ) {
               throw new IllegalStateException( "Unexpected item: '"+o1+"'");
            }
            final int i2;
            try{
               i2 = Integer.parseInt(p2[1].substring(0,p2[1].indexOf(':')));
            } catch( NumberFormatException x ) {
               throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected item: '"+o2+"'");
            }
            int cmp = p1[0].compareTo( p2[0] );
            if( cmp == 0 ) {
               cmp = i1 - i2;
            }
            return cmp;
         }});
      for( String entry : trendList ) {
         System.out.println( entry );
      }
   }
}
```

and the outputs:

```
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P0:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P1:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P2:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P3:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P4:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P5:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P6:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P7:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P8:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P9:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P10:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P11:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P12:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P13:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P14:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P15:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P0:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P1:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P2:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P3:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P4:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P5:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P10:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P11:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P12:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P13:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P14:8
ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P15:8
```

Comment: Very nice, but what is STR_LENGTH?

Comment: `ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S12` will come before `ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S2` if you don't check also the `S\\d+` number.

Comment: Ok, answer revised as you suggest.

Comment: This is very good. ONE last problem. What if there is a string which doesn't contain "_" or ":", but I still want that properly sorted? It seems substring( 0, p1[1].indexOf( ':' )) would break the code, since indexOf would return -1. What then would I reassign i1 and i2?

Comment: Error handling added. Please post an exhaustive specification of the input strings.

Comment: It's supposed to sort all string cases (NOT just ones containing ":" or "_"). Also, it's not helpful to just error out, but actually sort all strings. I posted a few sample cases that I sorted by hand, but would like the program to do. THANKS!!!

Comment: I did something like if(p1[1].indexOf( ':' ) == -1 || p2[1].indexOf(':' ) == -1) return 1; At least then it doesn't error out, but it doesn't correctly sort, either!

Comment: Also, I'm not assuming that two strings, say, ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S0_P8:8 and ACLK_SCRN_200MHZ_DATAB_S1_P0:8, are already sorted .. i.e. "S0" < "S1". This code ONLY sorts based on the numbers between the colons. I'm looking for a function which sorts the colon part AS WELL AS the string part

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number