# How to sort strings contains numbers in java

Tags: java, sorting

How can i sort strings contains numbers in java ?
Example : `abc12,abc2,xyz3,pqr23,pqr99,wer12` need to get `abc2,abc12,pqr23,pqr99,wer12` i tried with comparator but can only compare that of numbers need to compare both strings and numbers .
please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Which is the order of sorting?

Comment: small to high as am expressed in question

Comment: wer12 should't be after abc12?

Comment: `abc2` is before `abc12`?

Comment: this is the order i need abc2,abc12,pqr23,pqr99,wer12,xyz3

Comment: Looks like duplicate - please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number?rq=1

Comment: Manvendra Gupta let me check

Comment: what is the relative order of `ab1` and `abc1`according to your definition?

Comment: I have to agree with @KugathasanAbimaran there's no explicit sort criteria (other tan small to high...small what to high what..?)

Comment: Boris Strandjev like that question ab1 can be first

Comment: how to use that algorithm duplicated question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have always the format (`lettersNumbers`), you can use this regex (taken from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2345/simplify-splitting-a-string-into-alpha-and-numeric-parts) and slightly modified) :

```
private static final String PATTERN = "[^a-z0-9]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = Arrays.asList("abc12","abc2","xyz3","pqr23","pqr99","wer12");
        Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<String>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
                String [] arr0 = arg0.split(PATTERN);
                String [] arr1 = arg1.split(PATTERN);
                int cmp = arr0[0].compareTo(arr1[0]);
                return cmp != 0 ? cmp : Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(arr0[1]), Integer.parseInt(arr1[1]));
            }           
        });
        System.out.println(l);
    }
```

Output :

```
[abc2, abc12, pqr23, pqr99, wer12, xyz3]
```

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

One way of doing it in a simplistic manner would be pad the numbers with preceeding zeroes. 
so, say if you have strings such as

```
abc1
abc10 
abc100
```

You parse your strings and pad the strings which have numbers occupy the same space. 
so your strings would become

```
abc001
abc010
abc100
```

Now, just sort them, and the natural ordering should sort them beautifully without a hassle.

This is all provided you have a knowledge of how many numbers will constitute the part of the String.

Also, you might want to output them in the fashion of `abc001` instead of `abc1` since that would help your sorting immensly.

Can you not parse and update your strings to be from say `abc2` to `abc02`
If you do that, the sorting after that would just work fine. isnt it?

So, whereever there is just 1 number pad it before with a 0.

But, inspite of that it is still doable and an easier solution than the comparator in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Use natural sorting:

```
package org.cougaar.util;

import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * A sorting comparator to sort strings numerically,
 * ie [1, 2, 10], as opposed to [1, 10, 2].
 */
public final class NaturalOrderComparator<T> implements  Comparator<T> {

    public static final Comparator<String> NUMERICAL_ORDER = new NaturalOrderComparator<String>(false);
    public static final Comparator<String> CASEINSENSITIVE_NUMERICAL_ORDER = new NaturalOrderComparator<String>(true);

    private final boolean caseInsensitive;

    private NaturalOrderComparator(boolean caseInsensitive) {
        this.caseInsensitive = caseInsensitive;
    }

    int compareRight(String a, String b) {
        int bias = 0;
        int ia = 0;
        int ib = 0;

        // The longest run of digits wins.  That aside, the greatest
        // value wins, but we can't know that it will until we've scanned
        // both numbers to know that they have the same magnitude, so we
        // remember it in BIAS.
        for (;; ia++, ib++) {
            char ca = charAt(a, ia);
            char cb = charAt(b, ib);

            if (!Character.isDigit(ca) && !Character.isDigit(cb)) {
                return bias;
            } else if (!Character.isDigit(ca)) {
                return -1;
            } else if (!Character.isDigit(cb)) {
                return +1;
            } else if (ca < cb) {
                if (bias == 0) {
                    bias = -1;
                }
            } else if (ca > cb) {
                if (bias == 0)
                    bias = +1;
            } else if (ca == 0 && cb == 0) {
                return bias;
            }
        }
    }

    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        String a = o1.toString();
        String b = o2.toString();

        int ia = 0, ib = 0;
        int nza = 0, nzb = 0;
        char ca, cb;
        int result;

        while (true) {
            // only count the number of zeroes leading the last number compared
            nza = nzb = 0;

            ca = charAt(a, ia);
            cb = charAt(b, ib);

            // skip over leading zeros
            while (ca == '0') {
                if (ca == '0') {
                    nza++;
                } else {
                    // only count consecutive zeroes
                    nza = 0;
                }

                // if the next character isn't a digit, then we've had a run of only zeros
                // we still need to treat this as a 0 for comparison purposes
                if (!Character.isDigit(charAt(a, ia+1)))
                    break;

                ca = charAt(a, ++ia);
            }

            while (cb == '0') {
                if (cb == '0') {
                    nzb++;
                } else {
                    // only count consecutive zeroes
                    nzb = 0;
                }

                // if the next character isn't a digit, then we've had a run of only zeros
                // we still need to treat this as a 0 for comparison purposes
                if (!Character.isDigit(charAt(b, ib+1)))
                    break;

                cb = charAt(b, ++ib);
            }

            // process run of digits
            if (Character.isDigit(ca) && Character.isDigit(cb)) {
                if ((result = compareRight(a.substring(ia), b
                        .substring(ib))) != 0) {
                    return result;
                }
            }

            if (ca == 0 && cb == 0) {
                // The strings compare the same.  Perhaps the caller
                // will want to call strcmp to break the tie.
                return nza - nzb;
            }

            if (ca < cb) {
                return -1;
            } else if (ca > cb) {
                return +1;
            }

            ++ia;
            ++ib;
        }
    }

    private char charAt(String s, int i) {
        if (i >= s.length()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return caseInsensitive ? Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)) : s.charAt(i);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you please delete the copy pasted large class that brings no value to your answer?