# Android How to sort String List

Tags: android, string, list, sorting

I have a list with this kind of values:

> list[0] = "myvalue_8" 
>   list[1] = "myvalue_9" 
>   list[2] = "myvalue_15"
>   list[3] = "myvalue_12"

When I sort my list like that:

```
Collections.sort(myList);
```

The result is:

> list[0] = "myvalue_12" 
>   list[1] = "myvalue_15" 
>   list[2] = "myvalue_8"
>   list[3] = "myvalue_9"

instead of:

> list[0] = "myvalue_8" 
>   list[1] = "myvalue_9" 
>   list[2] = "myvalue_12"
>   list[3] = "myvalue_15"

Thank you very much

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number) for info on the Alphanum algorithm.

Comment: You could always drop the "myvalue_" part of the string, and sort yourself by using the remaining integers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Comparator`. There you define what to compare and how, in the `compare()` method you define what should be returned from two of your instances. Here's an example for a `String` `Comparator`.

```
Comparator<String> myComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(final String user1, final String user2) {
    // This would return the ASCII representation of the first character of each string
    return (int) user2.charAt(0) - (int) user1.charAt(0);
  };
};
```

Then you just call `Collections.sort(myList, myComparator);`