# Sorting different type Strings in List

Tags: java, string, sorting, java-stream, string-comparison

I have a list of string containing `AA0 AA5 BB2 BB9 AA1 BB13 AA7 AA2` not in order. What I want is two seperate categories ordered like `AA0 AA1 AA2 AA5 AA7 BB2 BB9 BB13` How could I do that?

I have tried `myList.stream().sorted(mySorter).foreach(...);` where `mySorter` like below:

```
  private final Comparator<String> mySorter= ( o1, o2 ) -> {
  try
  {
     final int first = Integer.parseInt( o1.substring( 2, o1.length() ) );
     final int second = Integer.parseInt( o2.substring( 2, o2.length() ) );
     System.out.println( o1 + " -> " + first + " " + o2 + " -> " + second );
     if ( o1.contains( "AA" ) && o2.contains( "BB" ) )
     {
        return -1;
     }
     else if ( o1.contains( "AA" ) && o2.contains( "AA" ) )
     {
        return first - second;

     }
     else if ( o1.contains( "BB" ) && o2.contains( "BB" ) )
     {
        return first - second;
     }
     return first - second;

  }
  catch ( final Exception e )
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return 0;
  }
  };
```

I am aware that it does contain unnecessarry if/else blocks but I am having `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!` at the same time which I have no idea why. Been trying to solve the exception and the algorithm could do what I want. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: will you always only have 2 Chars and then a number?

Comment: @dave Yes, I will be having 2 chars and then a number.

Comment: I'd probably split it differently then I'd compare on Chars first then on int, you can avoid the if else stuff then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort on a string that may contain a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number)

Comment: @dave I am already comparing the chars here, don't you think?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any comparator must follow these rules:

1. If `A<B` (as in, `a.compareTo(b)` returns a negative number), then `B>A` must be true (as in, if you were to call `b.compareTo(a)`, it **MUST** return a positive number).
2. `A=A` (`a.compareTo(a)` **MUST** return 0).
3. If `A<B` and `B<C` then this must hold: `A<C`.

That error means you aren't doing that.

It looks like you are stating that all AA categories precede all BB categories (via the line `( o1.contains( "AA" ) && o2.contains( "BB" ) )` , but you didn't add the reverse, where all BBs come after all AAs. You have to write it in pairs or it won't work. Fix that. Perhaps there are more violations, but, one step at a time.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.

Comment: nice answer; might be worth making the "must" in 3 into a "**MUST**", as transitivity is just as necessary as 1/2

Comment: Or use the factory methods which ensure symmetry intrinsically,i.e. `Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s.substring(0, 2))  .thenComparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2)))` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample example to solve sort given list of `string` in the format with first two character representing string and remaining forming integer.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  List<String>list = Arrays.asList("AA0", "AA5", "BB9", "BB2", "AA1", "BB13", "AA7", "AA2");

  Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<String>(){
     @Override
     public int compare(String o1,String o2) {
         String substr1 = o1.substring(0,2);
         String substr2 = o2.substring(0,2);
         Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(o1.substring(2));
         Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(o2.substring(2));

         int strCompare = substr1.compareTo(substr2); 
         int intCompare = num1.compareTo(num2);

         if (strCompare == 0)  return (intCompare == 0 ? strCompare : intCompare); 
         else return strCompare; 
       }
   });

   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
   }
}
```