# How to perform sort operation on a list having string and integer combination data like 1094 days, 1092 days, 994 days, 973 days

Tags: java

I have a list with value 994 days, 973 days, 1094 days, 1092 days, 189 days, 184 days and want to perform sort in ascending order. So when use Collections.sort() its sorting in incorrect order

```
  List<String>  list = new LinkedList<String>();
   list.add("994 days");
   list.add("973 days");
   list.add("1094 days");
   list.add("1092 days");
   list.add("189 days");
   list.add("184 days");
```

i want to sort this in ascending order so my output has to be : 184 days, 189 days, 973 days, 994 days,1092 days, 1094 days

Comment: if the pattern is going to be `"N days"` for every item, you can isolate the number (for example through regular expression = `^(\d+) days$`, group 1) and sort by that.

Comment: simply remove days and trim your String and then convert it to Integer sort and you will get your desired result. and again convert these value to sting array list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort on a string that may contain a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/104599/5221149)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Comparator.comparingInt` which required a function to extract an `int` from your object, in this case a `String`:

```java
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> Integer.valueOf(s.split(" ")[0])));
```

`Integer.valueOf(s.split(" ")[0])` will keep only the number from your string:

> "198 days" -> 198

Answer (score -1):

Add a comparator which extract integer part and returns the result accordingly.
Something like this.

```
class DatesCompare implements Comparator<String> 
{ 
    public int compare(String d1, String d2) 
    { 
        int d1num = Integer.parseInt(d1.split(" ")[0]);
        int d2num = Integer.parseInt(d2.split(" ")[0]);
        if (d1num < d2num) return -1; 
        if (d1num > d2num ) return 1; 
        else return 0; 
    } 
} 

Collections.sort(list, new DatesCompare())
```

Comment: `NumberFormatException: For input string: "973 "`

Comment: second d1.split should be d2.split