# Sort a list of strings in java in alphabetical order

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a list with some strings in this format:

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();

ids.add("B-7");
ids.add("B-5");
ids.add("A-3");
ids.add("B-8");
ids.add("B-1");
ids.add("B-6");
ids.add("B-2");
ids.add("B-3");
ids.add("B-10");
ids.add("A-1");
ids.add("B-4");
ids.add("B-9");
ids.add("A-2");
```

I need to sort it to have this output, (iterating over the list):

```
A-1
A-2
A-3
B-1
B-2
B-3
B-4
B-5
B-6
B-7
B-8
B-9
B-10
```

I am using:

```
List<String> sortedIds = ids.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But instead, my output:

```
A-1
A-2
A-3
B-1
B-10   -- Error
B-2
B-3
B-4
B-5
B-6
B-7
B-8
B-9
```

Comment: This is where the documentation comes in handy.  If you look at [`Stream#sorted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted()), notice that it says "sorted according to natural order."  As you've demonstrated, you don't want natural order, you want to sort it a different way.  Java is way ahead of you; it's got an [overloaded method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted(java.util.Comparator)) which lets you specify a custom Comparator.

Comment: [Sort on a string that may contain a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/104599/3890632)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) using `Comparator.comparing` and `Comparator.thenComparing`.

```
List<String> sortedIds = ids.stream().sorted(
    Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf('-')))
    .thenComparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.indexOf('-') + 1))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: By the way, that last line can be [`.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) in Java 16 and later.

Answer (score 4):

The default `Comparator` is going to operate in lexicographical order. You need to compare the String parts and Integer parts separately. Something like

```
Collections.sort(ids, (a, b) -> {
    String[] at = a.split("-");
    String[] bt = b.split("-");
    int c = at[0].compareTo(bt[0]);
    if (c != 0) {
        return c;
    }
    return Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(at[1])).compareTo(Integer.parseInt(bt[1]));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

What you'll need is a customer `Comparator<String>` to use inside of the `sorted()` intermediate operation

```
List<String> sorted = ids.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> {
    String[] first = o1.split("-");
    String[] second = o2.split("-");

    int lettersComparison = first[0].compareTo(second[0]);
    if (lettersComparison != 0) {
        return lettersComparison;
    }

    Integer firstNumber = Integer.valueOf(first[1]);
    Integer secondNumber = Integer.valueOf(second[1]);
    return firstNumber.compareTo(secondNumber);
}).toList();
```

Which outputs

```
[A-1, A-2, A-3, B-1, B-2, B-3, B-4, B-5, B-6, B-7, B-8, B-9, B-10]
```

---

That said, if you want to just sort the existing `List`, I would suggest not to go through a `Stream` for that because it has an overhead in terms of performance and creation of new object.

You can use `list.sort(comparator)` and use the same `Comparator<String>` as hereabove

```
ids.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    String[] first = o1.split("-");
    String[] second = o2.split("-");

    int lettersComparison = first[0].compareTo(second[0]);
    if (lettersComparison != 0) {
        return lettersComparison;
    }

    Integer firstNumber = Integer.valueOf(first[1]);
    Integer secondNumber = Integer.valueOf(second[1]);
    return firstNumber.compareTo(secondNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
List<String> ids = Arrays.asList(
    "B-7", "B-5", "A-3", "B-8", "B-1", "B-6", "B-2",
    "B-3", "B-10", "A-1", "B-4", "B-9", "A-2");

Collections.sort(ids,
    Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
    .thenComparing(Function.identity()));

System.out.println(ids);
```

output

```
[A-1, A-2, A-3, B-1, B-2, B-3, B-4, B-5, B-6, B-7, B-8, B-9, B-10]
```

Comment: Very smart ! But what if `B-05` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another way.  I tend to split first and then glue together after sorting rather than continually splitting inside a comparator.

```
List<String> result = ids.stream().map(s -> s.split("-"))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing((String[] a) -> a[0])
                .thenComparingInt(
                        a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1])))
        .map(a -> String.join(",", a))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```