# How to sort list of strings that contains numbers and special characters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to sort list of strings in this order:

`("7foo", "FOO1", "FOO2", "foo4", "foo4_1", "foo5", "foo5_1", "FOO8",  "Foo27_QA", "Foo29_QA")`

I tried to use `list.sortedWith{}`:

```kotlin
val list = mutableListOf("FOO1", "FOO2", "7foo", "FOO8", "foo5","foo27_QA", "foo4_1", "foo29_QA", "foo5_1", "foo4")

val sorted2 = list.sortedWith(compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, { it }))
```

but the result is:
`[7foo, FOO1, FOO2, Foo27_QA, Foo29_QA, foo4, foo4_1, foo5, foo5_1, FOO8]`

Comment: You can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number It is for Java, but it is pretty much the same.

Comment: @broot thanks for your help, I already tried some of the comments in the link you provided.

Comment: You need to start with describing the kind of order you want. I can't see any order in your goal, to me it looks completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the order you would like to get.

Default comparator, as well as `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` comparator, follows lexicographic order.  But, your expected result is not in such an order.

In lexicographic-case-insensitive order: `Foo29_QA` is before `foo4`. So the result is fine while using the default comparator.

So, you need to write your own comparator to apply your own logic.

```kotlin
val sorted3 = list.sortedWith { o1, o2 -> 
    // put your comparing logic here
}
```

Okey, so how to sort your list (this won't be an easy-peasy task).
I assume that your orders follows the pattern:

> `{$number_prefix}{"foo"}{$number}{"_"}{$alphanumeric_suffix}`

And we would like to sort it by:

- `$number_prefix` DESC
- `$number` ASC
- `$alphanumeric_suffix` DESC

So, finally, we can use something like:

```kotlin
// create helper class for comparing
data class Element(
    val originalValue: String,
    val numberPrefix: Int?,
    val number: Int?,
    val suffix: String
)

// parse string into Element (for strings that not follow pattern
// `{$number_prefix}{"foo"}{$number}{"_"}{$alphanumeric_suffix}`
// this may throw an exception
fun parse(s: String): Element {
    val normalized = s.lowercase()
    val fooSplit = normalized.split("foo")

    // determine numberPrefix
    val numberPrefix = fooSplit.first().toIntOrNull()

    // parse the rest
    val suffixRest = fooSplit.last()
    val suffixRestSplit = suffixRest.split("_")

    // and get rest of the data
    val number = suffixRestSplit.first().toIntOrNull()
    val suffix = suffixRestSplit.last()

    return Element(s, numberPrefix, number, suffix)
}

fun test() {
    // define list
    val list = mutableListOf("FOO1", "FOO2", "7foo", "FOO8", "foo5", "foo27_QA", "foo4_1", "foo29_QA", "foo5_1", "foo4")

    // create a comparator with defined comparing rules
    val elementComparator = compareByDescending <Element> { it.numberPrefix }
        .thenBy { it.number }
        .thenByDescending { it.suffix }

    // and sort it with the defined comparator (map it in the fly)
    val sorted = list
        .map { parse(it) } // parse to helper-Element class
        .sortedWith(elementComparator) // compare with our defined rules
        .map { it.originalValue } // go back to original values

    // prints: [7foo, FOO1, FOO2, foo4, foo4_1, foo5, foo5_1, FOO8, foo27_QA, foo29_QA]
    println(sorted)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve the order?

Comment: Could you explain what order do you expect here? As I see, the patter here is something like: `{$number_prefix}{"foo"}{$number}{"_"}{$alphanumeric_suffix}`, right? And you need to sort the collection by each component separately, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this function to extract the number

```
fun getNumber(s: String) = ("foo(\\d+)".toRegex().find(s.lowercase())?.groups?.get(1)?.value ?: "0").toInt()
```

then you can do

```
val sorted2  = list.sortedWith(compareBy({
    getNumber(it)
}, { it }))
```